# pickle, 'str' does not support buffer interface in python

Tags: python

Ok so I have the following code:

```
def rate_of_work(self):
    global rate
    rate = (turtle.textinput("Your Work Rate","What is your hourly work rate in US Dollars?"))
    outFile_rate = pickle.dumps(rate)

rate1 = pickle.loads(rate)
rate2 = ((hours*rate1) + (minutes*rate1)*0.0167 + (seconds*rate1)*0.000278) #isnt necessary information
rate3 = round(rate2, 2) #isnt necessary information
```

im getting the error:

```
rate1 = pickle.loads(rate)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

please help

Comment: Your code never sets `rate`.

Comment: What is the point of `outFile_rate`?

Comment: This error can't be reproduced with code provided, as pickled value is never saved or returned.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are working under python 3.x

For the specific error, pickle.loads() only accepts bytes, and you are trying to give a plain string to it, that's why it fails.

```
>>> pickle.loads("")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
>>> pickle.loads(b"")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
EOFError
```